# How to find out why a MathJax equation is not being rendered?

Tags: mathjax

I am using MathJax with locally-defined macros to display equations (in documentation generated by sphinx). Recently, some of the equations are not shown properly anymore -- the source is shown in the frame, but not the actual formula. Most equations show up just fine, within the same page (https://woodem.org/theory/leapfrog.html):
[image: rendered webpage]
Is there a way to find out why MathJax does not display the first equation? All the macros used are defined (some of them are used in the second eq.), there is no message in the JS console, MathJax context menu (right-click on the eq frame) gives no hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect is due to the `noErrors` extension (which is part of the combined configuration file). Since it's better to keep the combined config, you can disable the extension in your custom inline configuration.

As per [the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=noerrors#noerrors), add to the TeX section of your inline configuration:

```
TeX: { ..., noErrors: { disabled: true } }
```

This will get you typical LaTeX warnings. (In your case, probably about the ampersands which are only allowed in table-like environments).